# BGcolor change in servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I'm creating an application where i have to fetch details from database and display it using JSP and servlet. In my window i have two options search and find. i can work well with search. but in find I'm finding difficulty. 
From jsp if i give the the employee id and click the find button. it has to display the entire database details by highlighting the corresponding id and the records belongs to  that id. i.e the complete row should be highlighted. i cant able highlight or change the bgcolor of particular row. anyone please help me in this.i am pasting mycode here. Thanku.

```
                 out.println("mark "+"{" 

                    +"background-color: yellow"

                    +"color: black" 

                    +"}");





            if (radio.equals("find")) {

            String Employee_id = request.getParameter("Employee_Id");

            if (Employee_id != null)

            {
                sql1 = "SELECT * from Employee";
                int rowCount = 0;
                out.println("<P ALIGN='center'><TABLE BORDER=1>");
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql1);
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
                // table header
                out.println("<TR>");
                for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
                    out.println("<TH>" + rsmd.getColumnLabel(i + 1)
                            + "</TH>");
                }
                out.println("</TR>");
                // the data
                while (rs.next()) {
                    rowCount++;
                    if (Employee_id.equals(rs.getString(1)))
                    {
                        out.println("<TR>");
                        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
                            out.println("<TD><mark>" + rs.getString(i + 1)
                                    + "</mark></TD>");

                        }
                        out.println("</TR>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        out.println("<TR>");
                        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
                            out.println("<TD>" + rs.getString(i + 1)
                                    + "</TD>");
                        }
                        out.println("</TR>");
                    }
                }
```

Comment: anyone please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather a CSS/HTML question, than JSP/Servlets one, IMHO.

Anyway, have you checked the generated HTML? Does the `<mark>` tag appear in the proper table line? What browser do you use? The above (the `<mark>` tag) is an HTML5 markup, might not work in old browsers.

Another possible cause: is the style definition (`mark { background-color: ... }`) properly defined inside `<style>` tag?

Comment: hi @ 
Jozef Chocholacek no i din check with style. im using firefox

Comment: <style> tag is deleting the entire record of that particular id. can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Would you mind to paste the generated HTML somewhere, so we can inspect it?